# Re-set spawn after collision

Tags: lua, coronasdk, collision

Basically what happens is objects spawn off screen at random positions and then flow in and out of the screen view. 
as they flow of screen they reset at a random position off screen again, however I cannot get that to happen if the player collides with it.

So to summarise, how would I make the object position respawn off screen again on collision with player?

Heres the object code.

```
UFO = display.newImage("ufo.png")
  UFO.name = "UFO"
  UFO.x = 640
  UFO.y = 100
  UFO.speed = math.random(2,6)
  UFO.initY = UFO.y
  UFO.amp = math.random(20,100)
  UFO.angle = math.random(1,360)
  physics.addBody(UFO, "static")
```

---

```
function moveUFO(self,event)
  if self.x < -50 then
     self.x = math.random(500,1500)
     self.y = math.random(90,220)
     self.speed = math.random(2,6)
     self.amp = math.random(20,100)
     self.angle = math.random(1,360)
else 
    self.x = self.x - self.speed
    self.angle = self.angle + .1
    self.y = self.amp*math.sin(self.angle)+self.initY
end
```

Here is the code for collision detection

```
    function ship:collision(event)
            if (event.other.name == 'UFO') then
                    event.other:removeSelf(self)
                    scoreAnim = display.newText('+10', ship.x, ship.y-10, native.systemFontBold, 16)
                    transition.to(scoreAnim, {time = 1000, y = scoreAnim.y - 30, alpha = 0, onComplete = function() display.remove(scoreAnim) scoreAnim = nil end})
                    scoreAnim:setTextColor(0,255,12)
                   --increases score
                    collectedN.text = tostring(tonumber(collectedN.text) + 1)
```

ship:addEventListener("collision", onCollision, ship, addTime)

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand you don't know about collision detection. You should study this page:http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection

edit part:

```
function ship:collision(event)
    if (event.other.name == 'UFO') then
          timer.performWithDelay( 50, function() event.other.x = math.random( 0, 320 ); event.other.y = math.random( 0.480 ); end, 1 )
          scoreAnim = display.newText('+10', ship.x, ship.y-10, native.systemFontBold, 16)
          transition.to(scoreAnim, {time = 1000, y = scoreAnim.y - 30, alpha = 0, onComplete = function() display.remove(scoreAnim) scoreAnim = nil end})
          scoreAnim:setTextColor(0,255,12)
          --increases score
          collectedN.text = tostring(tonumber(collectedN.text) + 1)
```

This will do it.. You can modify random values over there. And you couldn't move your object right in collision time, because Corona physics, lock all physics objects in collision time. So you should move your objects right after collision.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply and for the links. I do understand most of collision detection and have some working ones setup but only to destroy on collision. Im just struggling in trying to reset its body off screen again so that it flows back in. Kinda like a floating collectable star. Any idea how i can reset its position again?

Comment: If you edit your question including the code block where you detect collisions, I can help easly

Comment: Thanks for helping, ive edited my question as you requested. Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't understad why you remove UFO named object. Dont you want to update it's position instead of removing it?

Comment: I was trying to re-spawn it when I last worked on it but never worked. I do want to update its position to a random x and y after collision.